# Bijection bewteen $(-1,1)$ and $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=x^3\}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I am trying to show that $(-1,1)$ and $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=x^3\}$ are homeomorphic, with the standard metrics. I cant see how to define a bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to show $(-1,1)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (via $\tan$ and some modifications for example) and then $\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphic to $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=x^3\}$